# Using jQuery Dialog

Tags: php, jquery, dialog

I have a HTML table and I get data for each cell from database.Some cells have an edit icon, so when the user clicks on it, he should see a pop up dialog. In this dialog there should be a drop down menu with 3 options.And after the user selects one of them and clicks on save button, the database should get updated. Previously instead of using jQuery Dialog I was using prompt and the user had to type the new status.But now I want to use dialog.

The following is part of my code in the tracking.php file.

```
                    <td>
                       <?php
                      $var=$arrayD['Structural Data Loaded']; 
                      echo
                      '<a data-id="$id" class="StructuralDataLoaded">' . $var . ' <img class="img" onclick="javascript:SelectStatus(data-id);" src="images/edit.png"></a>';
                      ?>
                   </td>




        /* Selecting new status DIV */
           <div id="SelectingStatus" title="Select Status" style="display:none;">
       <h>
            Select the status
       </h>

       <select>
             <option value="Not Started">Not Started</option>
             <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
             <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
       </select>

    </div>


    <script>

function SelectStatus(id) {

$('#SelectingStatus').dialog('destroy');
    var SelectingStatus = $('#SelectingStatus');
    SelectingStatus.dialog({
        close: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).dialog('destroy');
        },
        modal: true,
        title: 'Select Status',
        width: 600,
        height: 'auto',
        overlay: {
            backgroundColor: '#000000',
            opacity: 0.5
        },

    });
```

}

right now when I am clicking on the editicon, I do not see any pop up dialog. What is the problem?

Comment: Do you get any JS errors in the console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a functionSelectStatus @ tracking.php:389onclick @ tracking.php:111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dialog is a jQuery UI feature](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/). Given the error message you get it looks like you haven't loaded jquery-ui.js.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I also had to remove the liens $(this).dialog('destroy'); and $('#SelectingStatus').dialog('destroy'); so it is working now. Do you know why it did not work when I had $('#SelectingStatus').dialog('destroy'); and  $(this).dialog('destroy'); ?

Comment: I do not. Did you get any JS error message in the console? Maybe you ment `.dialog('close')`?